# Homogeneous distribution

Tags: distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

In Wikipedia, it says The Dirac delta function is homogeneous of degree −1, with the following formula:

[image]

However, I can not understand why the last equality is true. Can someone show me the detailed computation?

Thanks!

Comment: $\int f\delta = f(0)$ is the *definition* of $\delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search on the internet, I found the following explanation, which I think can solve my puzzle:

$\int f(x)\delta(x) dx = \int f(0)δ(x) dx = f(0) \int δ(x) dx = f(0)$, since $f(x)δ(x)$ and $f(0)δ(x)$ are the same since they are both zero for every $x \neq 0$, and $\int \delta (x)= 1$ by the property of the Dirac delta function.